# What is meant by "windows" in Workbook.Protect

Tags: excel, vba

When using `Workbook.Protect`, what does the `Windows` argument do?

According to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect), you can set it to

> True to protect the workbook windows. If this argument is omitted, the windows aren't protected.

Some further googling led me to [this page](http://codevba.com/excel/protect_workbook.htm), which claims that

> The Windows option prevents the user from creating additional windows for the workbook.

I am, however, no wiser in regards to what exactly a window in this context is referring to.

So, does someone here have an idea of what "windows" is referring to in this context?

Comment: I think you are referring the the "Windows Option" which you get when you are trying to protect the workbook? That feature is now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/programming-for-the-single-document-interface-in-excel#odc_xl15_ta_ProgrammingtheSDIinExcel2013_Deprecating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally means windows, as a workbook can be in multiple open windows. :) If  you select that option, you can't use the New Window button to have multiple views of the same workbook, nor can you resize/move any existing workbook windows.

Comment: I always wondered as to why they removed that feature. I really loved it. Helped me make custom views... I guess becuase of MDI->SDI?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I guess you can't have everything :)

Comment: After doing `Workbooks("wb1.xlsm").Protect Windows:=true, structure:=true` I am still able to resize the window the workbook is in though - is it just a depreceated feature as @SiddharthRout says in a comment on the question? Ditto for new window, I have no problems using that button after running the line of code above

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If it's an SDI one, then yes @SiddharthRout's comment will apply.

Comment: Yeah, it's an SDI version, so I guess it's no surprise that I couldn't notice any changes no matter what I set the argument to :-) It may be worth mentioning in your answer that it is depreceated for SDI versions of Excel, as I haven't found this info elsewhere (i.e. my googling didn't bring me to the site Siddharth found).